# How to find difference between two datetimes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

How to calculate difference between two datetimes and get answer in hours? Datetime format is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: Datetimes don't have intrinsic human-readable formats; that's just how your client is displaying the data for you. Unless you're storing the data as strings, which would not be a good idea. Is the data type date or timestamp? And what do you want to do when the difference isn't an exact number of hours - round to nearest hour, or higher/lower?

Comment: @AlexPoole it is data type date. I want to calculate difference between current date and date from table and find out if it is less or equal to 1 hour.

Comment: OK, then you can adapt what Littlefoot showed to use the columns from your table instead of fixed dates.

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract two DATE values, the result is number of days. Therefore, to get number of hours, you have to multiply the result by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day).

For example:

```
SQL> select to_date('12.11.2018 10:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  2       - to_date('12.11.2018 08:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') number_of_days
  3  from dual;

NUMBER_OF_DAYS
--------------
    ,083333333

SQL> select (  to_date('12.11.2018 10:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  2          - to_date('12.11.2018 08:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  3         ) * 24 number_of_hours
  4  from dual;

NUMBER_OF_HOURS
---------------
              2
```

By the way, format mask you posted is wrong; it is not HH:**MM**:SS but HH:MI:SS; MM is for months, MI is for minutes.